# TSQL query with join and split data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure set up like this:

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
        BEGIN
            SELECT  A.[campaignID],
                    A.[campaignTitle],
                    A.[campaignDesc],
                    A.[campaignType],
                    A.[campaignStatus],
                    A.[dataNeeded],
                    A.[duration],
                    A.[whoCreated],
                    B.[type],
                    CONVERT (VARCHAR (20), dateCreated, 100) AS dateCreated
            FROM   [dbo].[Tags_Campaigns] A
            INNER JOIN  [dbo].[Tags_Data_Types] B
            ON A.campaignType = B.id
            WHERE A.[campaignID] = @campaignID
            FOR    XML PATH ('campaign'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
        END 
END
```

It joins on a table that stores the types which looks like:

[image]

My output is generated like so:

```
            <root>
             <campaign>
            <campaignID>31</campaignID>
            <campaignTitle>Testing</campaignTitle>
            <campaignDesc>This is a test campaign to see what happens with stuff.</campaignDesc>
            <campaignType>2</campaignType>
            <campaignStatus>Active</campaignStatus>
            <dataNeeded>2,1</dataNeeded>
            <duration>21</duration>
            <whoCreated>carl</whoCreated>
            <type>Case</type>
            <dateCreated>Nov 23 2013  6:48PM</dateCreated>
          </campaign>
        </root>
```

As you can see, it joined the  which is what I want however it only got one of them from the 1,2 input.

How would I be able to get the result to look like

```
  <type>PayPal Account,Case</type>
  <dataNeeded>1,2</dataNeeded>
```

Comment: This is why [dataNeeded] never should have been stored like that.

Comment: What would be another way to store it within the same record ?

Comment: @SSB it shouldn't be in a single record, that's a violation of First Normal Form for this relationship.

Comment: Well I meant how else can I reference the data I need into this single campaign record (not single column)

Comment: If you have a comma separated list in a single field, your database has a big problem. If you don't have time to fix it, you still may be able to make a hacky, non-professional solution if you need a quick fix. If so, can you provide this result: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT dataNeeded) FROM [Tags_Campaigns];

Comment: I am all for learning the correct way to do things, I simply did it because that's all I knew how to do. I have 2 separate tables , one is called Campaigns and the other is Data Types. When you create a campaign, you can select as many data types as you wish. I needed to store the data types selected with that campaign record. What would be a better solution to this ?

Comment: You create a child table of the campaign table that maps the campaign(s) onto the data type(s) - so the child table has a PK, and an FK for the campaign and the data type (one for each data type that relates to the campaign).